# Report to include specific URL click rate

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, email-studio

I want to run a report that includes not only the general open rate/click rate but the click rate on specific links.  I can't seem to find an option for that within Analytics Builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to another question posted.  Unique link tracking can be done using automation studio `Data Extract` with a `File Transfer` activity to the FTP.

[Unique click reporting discrepancies](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/210811/unique-click-reporting-discrepancies)