# Unique click reporting discrepancies

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-studio

I'm having an issue reconciling the reported unique link clicks vs the link-by-link display in the Email Studio > Sends > Click Activity.

This is on the journey overview page:
[image: This is on the journey overview page]

This is on the click activity page:
[image]

This issue is that the overview page is showing 17,500 clicks, but the click activity page is showing a subtotal of ~ 29,800.
When I pulled a report based on all these link clicks from the data view `_click`, I am getting close to the 17,500 (though not exact).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click activity page is separated out by UniqueClickbyURL (I believe), so there would be more clicks if you added all the links unique clicks together.

This is because the same person can click on multiple links - and each will show as a unique value.

Example:

1. Joe clicks link A, B, C, and D in your email.
2. Joe will count as just 1 unique click in job click tracking and in _click dataview.
3. Inside the click activity page, Joe will count as 4 unique clicks as the unique column is based solely on the URL.  So Joe would show up in link A as unique, link B as unique, link C as unique and link D as unique.

Another way to view UniqueClickbyURL is inside a tracking extract.  See below Screen Shot for where you would need to 'check' to receive this info:

[image: Include Unique For URLClicks]

Comment: That makes sense.  Based on the way `job click tracking` and `_click` dataview are tracked, is there no way to report on unique by link tracking outside of the `click activity page`?

Comment: Yes, it is available via Tracking Extract. It is severely under documented, but should be an option you can choose. Will add a screen shot to my answer